# How do I override the style for a specific element in JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I'am maintaining a small in-house Webapp built using JQueryUI.

I want a textarea to use a different font style then the theme-wide font style specified in the generated jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css.

I can of course edit the css file and specify the style for textarea globally, but that would make it hard to maintain the theme since if the theme is edited using the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) then that style has to be patched again.

So I thought that adding a new class to the local style.css and let textarea.testscript override the global textarea style and then use class="testscript" on the textarea would work but not...

For some reason, JQueryUI adds the default styles on top of the class applied style, according to the DOM Inspector in chrome its the following hierarchy that applies:

element.style {
}

**Matched CSS Rules**
*jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css:52*
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

*style.css:101*
textarea.testscript {
  <strike>font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;</strike>
  <strike>font-size: 12px;</strike>
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

In the DOM Hierarchy, the only class active on the textarea element is class="testscript", the parent element higher up in the DOM has the ui-widget class, but I thought that the style specified by the element class would override styles inehrited from the parents classes, am I wrong?

**EDIT**

Fixed it, changing the order of the inclusion of style sheets in the HTML header fixed it, now the class="testscript" style declared in style.css has precedence over the ui-widget .textarea declared in jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css.

This did not work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css"/>
```

This works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a matter of specificity ( http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html ). You really should always include your custom styles **AFTER** any framework files for this very reason. That way, overwriting styles becomes easier and more intuitive.